# Use a dropdown to filter results within my dataProvider in GridView widget (Yii 1.x)

Tags: php, gridview, yii, frameworks, yii-components

Within my Yii 1.x application I am using the GridView widgets to display tabular data. I'd like to have a simple dropdown that will allow me to filter the results.

In this instance I have a set of 'Reward' data - each reward will either be 'Positive' OR 'Negative'. And I'd like to have a dropdown that will filter between the two.

Here is my code:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
'dataProvider' => $model->search(true, $drill, isset($drillVal) ? $drillVal : false, isset($drillField) ? $drillField : false),
'filter' => $model,
'id' => get_class($model),
'type' => 'striped bordered condensed',
'template' => $model->getGridTemplate(),
'pagerCssClass' => 'pull-right pagination pagination-sm',
'columns' => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'reward_name',
        'filter' => false
    ),
    array(
        'name'              => 'reward_type',
        'header'            => 'Reward Type',
        'filter'            => false // need some code here for filtering
    ),
    array(
        'name'              => 'totalPoints',
        'header'            => 'Total Points',
        'filter'            => false
    ),
),
));
```

For example this will look like the following....

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| Reward Name | Reward Type | Total Points|
+-----------------------------------------+
|  Good Work  |   Positive  |     500     |    
| Great Effort|   Positive  |     150     |
|   Naughty   |   Negative  |     -75     |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I'd like the the filtering to allow me to show ONLY 'negatives' OR only 'positives'

Can anyone suggest how I best go about doing this?

Note - in my search() within the criteria element there is an IF statement as follows:

```
'IF(t.type="1","Deduction","Achievement") AS reward_type',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to have a dropdown list inside your view:

```
CHtml::dropDownList('rewardType', $rewardType, array(0 =>"-", 1=>"Positive", 2=>"Negative"), array(
    'onchange' =>
    "$.fn.yiiGridView.update('yourGridID(without # sign)',{ data:{rewardType: $(this).val() }})",
));
```

You can also use manual dropdown list(without yii) and send ajax request on `onchange` event and update gridView on success event of ajax request.

Now you need to add this code inside your `$model->search()` method(after initialize `$criteria`):

```
if(isset($_POST['rewardType']) && ($_POST['rewardType'] != 0))
{
    Yii::app()->session['rewardType'] = $_POST['rewardType'];
    $criteria->addCondition("t.reward_type = ".$_POST['rewardType']);
}
```

And the final work is to adding one line at the beginning of your view file:

```
<?php $rewardType= (isset(Yii::app()->session['rewardType'])) ? Yii::app()->session['rewardType'] : 0; ?>
```

I have implemented similar situation recently. I had a dropdown list for changing page size inside CGridView and use this solution. Hope my solution can help you too.

Comment: I figured it out without using this in the end but your method looks perfect too. Thanks